# Is there a way to get my browser to remember field values based on HTML field-ID?

Tags: browser, plugins, automation

Is there a way to get my browser to remember field values based on HTML field-ID ?  Is there a plugin or something?  What I want is if the browser detects a HTML field called "eyecolor" and I put cursor focus on it, I want the browser to give me a dropdown of things to select from that I have chosen in previous browser sessions.

Is this possible?  Is there a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

This is a native Firefox feature as long as the field doesn't set `autocomplete="no"`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case (in general). I do remember seeing something like what your suggesting in certain cases but you dont get a dropdown until you start typing. I'd like a immediate dropdown to appear. My guess is that something like this doesn't exist.

Comment: Or you could push the down arrow button.

Answer (score 0):

I think Firefox does this natively, but not very well.
[Lazarus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6984/) is probably what you're looking for.